# How do I install browser extensions to Firefox, Chrome or Edge browsers in Windows 10 as a regular user?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-addons

Since morning I have been trying to install add-ons for Firefox, Chrome and the Edge browsers, but I have achieved little success. I have only been able to install these to administrator accounts but not my regular user account. I see no errors. I have already tried reinstalling browsers multiple times.

Specifically, I tried installing LastPass in a number of ways but have not succeeded with any browser. In Chrome, I did get the error "Could not move extension directory into profile" but for other browsers, it was a silent fail.

This is a desktop and I am the administrator as a different account. I created this account for surfing purposes. How do I give this account temporary power to install addons?

So my questions is, "How do I install browser extensions to Firefox, Chrome or Edge browsers in Windows 10 as a regular user?"

Comment: Sounds like the Administrator has blocked your ability to install addons.

Comment: How do I unblock this after logging in as administrator?

Comment: Using your hint, I was able to install the addon to firefox but not chrome

Comment: Are you connected to a active directory domain

Comment: Temporarily grant your "surfing" account administrative permissions, install the add-ons, then revoke the admin rights. I'll post an answer when your question gets opened if you ping me @Twisty.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox can be installed as a user and then it won't be affected by the group policy

Comment: @Ramhound, no It's just a desktop machine with two accounts